# Looking for a Korean Thesaurus

Tags: resources

Are there any online thesauruses available for Korean, where I can search for synonyms (유의어) of a given word?

After searching online, I found hints that there might be one on Naver 국어사전, but couldn't find a link anywhere.

Comment: +1 I'm interested, too, though I have to say, I've found in English that a thesaurus can help me find words that other people haven't used which spices up what I'm writing/saying, while in Korean, I've found that being certain to use the phrases other people are writing/saying is the norm and expected.  That's probably due in part to my not being a native speaker, but in general, Koreans tend to do what other Koreans are doing.  So that in itself is a gap in culture from what we do in the West in trying to seek individuality, including our speech patterns.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't use it for finding rare words.  My passive vocabulary is much larger than my active vocabulary, so there are many times when I can't think of the right word, only a common word with a somewhat similar meaning.  At those times, a thesaurus could help me find the right word (that I already know, but only passively).

Answer (score 3):

Naver Korean dictionary partially supports thesaurus feature like this:

[image: Naver Korean Dictionary]

But still 'partial', so if you want to search directly for synonyms, visiting (주) 낱말 - a company offering its resources to Naver - directly may help you.

Go to the homepage ( http://www.natmal.com/ ) and click 'word gallery' on the top right, then click '비슷한말 반대말' in the left bar. Top search box would be for synonyms, and for acronyms below.

Comment: (주) 낱말 also has thesaurus app with two options: free and paid. Link to free version: iOS https://itunes.apple.com/kr/app/id518959067 Android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordnet.dic.synonym.lite

Comment: Looks like Natmal doesn't have free service anymore, could someone verify this please?

Answer (score 2):

In the [*National Institute of Korean Language's Korean-English Learners' Dictionary*](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/mainAction?nation=eng), you can view the semantic relations of a certain vocabulary such as synonyms, antonyms, heavy isotopes of a word, light isotopes of a word, emphatic variants of a word, soft variants of a word, original words, short forms, respectful forms, low forms, reference words, etc. For example, here are related words of the search word 아버지:

[image: Related words of the search word 아버지]

The related words are not as extensive as Naver's 관련어휘, but I really like how they have different categories and show different levels for the variants.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a website which is really very good for [Korean language](https://koreanly.com) learners. It has almost everything that is needed to become proficient in Korean. If you want to learn **[Korean thesaurus, Korean synonyms, Korean antonyms, Korean opposite words](https://koreanly.com/korean-synonyms-and-korean-antonyms/)** please visit this page.